# There is something wrong with my flutter sdk but I don't know what's it

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I can't run any flutter project on my pc. This is the error "cannot access implicit script receiver class 'org.gradle.api.Project' check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies.

I have done flutter pub get, flutter upgrade, flutter clean in no particular other. Delete flutter sdk and install a new one but none word